# dimension of span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

It is obvious that the first two vectors are linearly dependent on one another, therefore one of them does not contribute to the dimension of the subspace. The null vector also clearly does not contribute to the subspace. That leaves the 4 middle vectors which seem to be linearly independent of another which implies that the dimension of the subspace is 4.

However, the answer key says the answer is 3 dimensions. Any insight?

Comment: Answer is right.

Comment: How about verifying algebraically whether they are independent or not instead of guessing?

Comment: Try to write the first vector as a linear combination of the 3rd, 4th, and 5th in the list. It is doable, so you could think of the first two as not contributing to the dimension of the subspace (or one of the others, depending on your perspective)

Comment: This is from one of the GRE subject math test and each question should only take 2.5 minutes, I just wanted to see if there was a quick and obvious way to see the linearly independence.

Comment: The way I saw what I said: the four vectors I pointed out all have a zero in the same coordinate. So the span of the four vectors is a 3-dimensional subspace, and 4 vectors contained in a 3 dimensional subspace implies they are linearly dependent. Easily doable, it took me less than 15 seconds to see.

Comment: You can't just count shared zeros in general, though, you need to evaluate the dimension of the subspace spanned by the vectors. If there are more vectors in the list than the dimension of the subspace spanned by them, they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Right, so you observed that the 4 middle vectors all have 0 in the 3rd component, therefore, these 4 vectors span a 3-d supspace. And since the number of vectors is greater than the dimension of the subspace, one of them MUST be dependent on another out of the 4. Therefore, the subspace is 3-d. Is this correct logic?

Comment: Well, that tells you the the dimension is *at most* 3. You still have to eliminate 2 as a possibility.

Comment: amd is correct. When writing, I did not write the step I did in my head where I verified that the span was also strictly larger than 2, which I should have detailed in my writing for completeness. Sorry for that. It's easy to check, though. Clearly vectors 1 and 3 are linearly independent, and vector 4 can't be written as a linear combo of 1 and 3, because it has a nonzero 4th coordinate and 1 and 3 have zeros in their 4th coordinate. So the list contains 3 linearly independent vectors and is therefore of dimension at least 3.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $4$ middle vectors are **not** linearly independent.

All $4$ have their $3rd$ row zero.

Comment: To elaborate, all vectors all exist within a three dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ (*the subspace described by the third entry being zero*), and thus can span at most a subspace of size three.  All that would remain is to find a set of three which are linearly independent (which the first, third, and fourth are).